# JSON - split every second comma in object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have JSON object like this:

```
"data": [
      {
        "from": "2017-01-06",
        "to": "2017-01-07"
      },
      {
        "from": "2017-01-28",
        "to": "2017-02-05"
      }
    ]
```

And I want display it on my screen. But firstly, I need to split datas to form:

```
from: 2017-xx-xx, to: 0000-00-00,
from: 2017-xx-xx, to: 0000-00-00
```

Every replace works, but still I've got a problem with every second comma.

I have already code like:

```
controllers.filter('newFilter', function () {
return function (item) {
    var json = JSON.stringify(item);
    if (json) {
        json = json.replace(/"/g, "");
        json = json.replace(/{|}/gi, "");
        json = json.split(',').join("\n");
        json = json.substring(1, json.length - 1);
        return json;
    }
};
});
```

And I've got:

```
from: 2017-xx-xx, 
to: 0000-00-00,
from: 2017-xx-xx, 
to: 0000-00-00
```

How to change line with split and join to do that?

@edit about html displaying - this values are in data-title as tooltip:

```
 <tr class="pointer" ng-repeat="plan in plans">
     <td class="nowrap">{{plan.person}}</td>
     <td class="yearView" ng-repeat="month in plan.data"
         bs-tooltip data-title="{{month.dataTest| newFilter}}"
         data-container="body">
```

It's just a quite strange example, because in January I will have only one data from-to, but maybe for April I'll get 4-5 datas from-to. My english may be hard still.

I wanted to create a filter, because I gave up with the rest of my ideas.

@edit2 -> okay, I pasted my data but it's only a fragment of JSON.

My whole json for every person I have in my database:

```
 {
    "person": "John Smith",
    "Id": 50,
    "data": [
      {
        "month": 1,
        "maxDay": 31,
        "dataTest": [
          {
            "from": "2017-01-06",
            "to": "2017-01-07"
          },
          {
            "from": "2017-01-28",
            "to": "2017-02-05"
          }
        ]
      },
```

Comment: This is not how you parse JSON. `data[0].from` will directly give you the from date. Use that to make HTML.

Comment: Why not direct access to the JSON object? `data[0].from, data[0].to`

Comment: Why are you parsing the JSON like a string in the first place?

Comment: Rather than doing this, look into using ng-repeat in your template and formatting the data there.

Comment: Well, it's a problem, because it's into very big JSON object. When for January I've 3-4 datas from-to, I cant just do this by data[0].from. I dont really even know, how much datas I will have for every month

Comment: The edits have totally muddied the waters here.

Comment: *" I dont really even know, how much datas I will have for every month"* then how about something like `yourData.forEach(({from, to}) => console.log("from: %s, to: %s", from, to))`

Answer (score 2):

> And I want display it on my screen. But firstly, I need to split datas
>   to form:

No need to `stringify` the `item`, directly traverse the object's keys using `map` and `join`

```
var output = item.map( s => "from:" + s.from + ", to: " + s.to ).join( "\n" );
```

If it is for display on the screen, then wrap them in `div`'s

```
var output = item.map( s => "<div>from:" + s.from + ", to: " + s.to + "</div>" )
                 .join( "<br>" );
```

Or as a list item

```
var output = "<ul>" +
               item.map( s => "<li>from:" + s.from + ", to: " + s.to + "</li>" ).join( "" ) + 
             "</ul>";
```

Comment: As you can see, the OP wants to modify the original JSON.

Comment: I guess OP thinks that JSON modification is required. OP has mentioned *And I want display it on my screen. But firstly, I need to split datas to form:*

Comment: It's interesting, I will check it. Hope that you will help me in a few days :P Also edited my question.

Comment: @Kondziowsky Sorry I didn't understood the edits.. Please let me know how are they related to the original question you asked.

Comment: Edited it once more. That was only a fragment of my code and json, sorry :P But still I think your answer may help me. I will "callback" soon.